# Getting number of parameters for a class method

Tags: php, function, oop, reflection

I know:

```
function params($fn) {
    $R = new ReflectionFunction($fn);
    return $R->getNumberOfParameters();
}
```

returns the number of parameters the function can accept, but how do I do this for a method that exists in a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for instance add a new parameter $clazz to your function, in order to give a scope to the method you want to know the number of arguments. Instead of using ReflectionFunction, use ReflectionClass in addition with ReflectionMethod.

```
function params($clazz, $method) { 
    $C = new ReflectionClass($clazz);
    $M = $C->getMethod($method);
    return $M->getNumberOfParameters();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the function by accepting a `callable`:

```
function params(callable $fn)
{
    if (is_string($fn) || $fn instanceof \Closure) {
        $r = new ReflectionFunction($fn);
    } elseif (is_array($fn)) {
        if (is_object($fn[0])) {
            $c = new ReflectionObject($fn[0]);
        } else { // assume string
            $c = new ReflectionClass($fn[0]);
        }
        $r = $c->getMethod($fn[1]);
    }
    return $r->getNumberOfParameters();
}

params(['Foo', 'bar']); // get nr of arguments for Foo::bar()
params([new Foo, 'bar']); // get nr of arguments for $foo->bar()
params('foo'); // get nr of arguments for foo()
// ...
```

Comment: so the difference is that your way can accept an instance whereas the answer by Jerome can't?

Comment: Possibly; the main point is that you don't have to change the signature of `params()` to accomplish it.

Comment: +1 as it is a nice comprehensive function,  although it does answer the question, Jerome was first with one that solved my issue.